# Provider Hosted App in sharepoint online without using Azure

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, azure

can we develop a Provider Hosted App in SharePoint online without using Azure?
 Or is it only possible only in SharePoint on-premise?
 If possible please provide some reference.
 Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q: Can we develop a Provider Hosted App in SharePoint online without using Azure?**

A: Yes, it is possible to develop Provider Hosted App for SharePoint Online without using Azure.

**How?**

Lets have step by step procedure.

**Step-1**: Register your app using appregnew.aspx

Login to your SharePoint Online environment and navigate to the following URL for registering any new app on your site.

```
https://www.yoursiteurl/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx.
```

Generate **Client ID** and **Client Secret**.

Enter appropriate title for your app, Enter the domain where your app will be hosted and then enter the start up path for the app and click on **Create**

*Here domain is the server where your source code will be hosted*

**Step-2**: Record the Client Id and Client Secret key

After clicking on **Create** button if your details are valid then you will be redirected to the page where new **Client ID** and **Client Secret** Key will be displayed

**Step-3**: Create an App solution using visual studio.

- Open visual studio and click **`File -> New -> Project`**
- Select **Apps for SharePoint** and give appropriate name and click **OK**
- Provide the URL of your SharePoint Online environment and Choose
  **Provider-hosted** and click **Next**
- Once you click **Next** there will be login window, Login with your
  Office 365 credential and click **OK**
- Select “SharePoint Online” and click **Next**
- Here you can specify which kind of application you want to create,
  click on **Next**
- Select the Authentication setting, if you are going to use it for
  your SharePoint farm itself then you can use **Certificate** and
  process the steps for creating the public certificate, or else just
  select the default selection and click **Finish**
- Once you click on **Finish** your app creation part is done and you
  will be redirected to the default code page of the app. Add some line
  of sample code over here. Here you will observe then you have two
  project solution one is **ProjectName** and other one is
  **ProjectNameWeb**

**Step-4**: Update your web.config and AppManifest.xml file

- Update web.config with the **Client ID** and **Client Secret Key**
  which we recorded in Step-2.
- Also add  into the  section of
  web.config file if it gives some trust level issue.
- Update the AppManifest.xml with the Client Id

**Step-5**: Publish your code.

- Now your app is ready with sample code and now its time to publish
  the code.
- So just right click on the **ProjectName** and select **Publish**.
- Once you click on publish you will have publish window, Just create
  new profile and click **Next**
- Enter your app **Client Id** and **Client Secret key** again here and
  then click **Finish**

Once you are done with entering **Client Id** and **Client Secret Key** just click on **Deploy your web project** and follow your traditional way of publishing and publish your code to the domain which you specified at the time of App registration.

After successfully publishing your code to your domain just click on **Package the app**.

Once you click the **Package the app** you will be prompted to enter the url of your SharePoint Online where you have registered your app and **Client Id**, **Client Id** will be populated but please verify once with your original **Client Id**, if not same then enter your correct **Client Id** and click **Finish**

Once your app packaging is completed you will have your **ProjectName.app** file which is your app which will be installed on your SharePoint online environment

Now just upload this app to your app catalog and add to your site from site content. Your Provider Hosted App is ready.

Each and every step is performed and recorded, so if you face any difficulty please feel free to ask in comment section.

Comment: thanks for the steps. I also found another [link](http://bishwadebdey.blogspot.in/2016/01/step-by-step-creation-of-provider.html), its helped.